# mongodb mongoose how to undrestand that the given id is not found in populated ref

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-populate

I am creating a shop api in nodejs using mongoDB and mongoose. i have two models called users and products like so :

```
let userSchema = new schema({
    username: {
        type: schema.Types.String,
        required: true
    },
    liked: [{
        type: schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'product'
    }]
})
```

each user has a liked array which only product's ObjectId is stored in it as a ref and i use populate to get the name and price of the product like this:

```
                let liked = await user.findOne({username: username},{"liked":1,"_id":0}).populate({
                    path: 'liked',
                    options: {limit: 12, skip: (page - 1) * 12}
                })
                res.json(liked)
```

the problem is, when a user likes a product and the ref is added to the liked array and the admin of the shop removes that product from the products list when i fetch the liked products of that user no errors throws up(which is good!) and only the liked products that still exist in the products list is fetched and I dont have a way of knowing that the product is removed from the database so it should be removed from the liked array of that user. in this way a lot of my database space would be full because of object ids stored in liked array of users that dont exist anymore

Answer (score 0):

i found a souution myself like this it is time consuming but it workes :XD

```
let likedArray = await user.findOne({username: username}).select({"liked": 1, "_id": 0})

let liked = await user.findOne({username: username},{"liked":1,"_id":0}).populate({path: 'liked',
options: {limit: 12, skip: (page - 1) * 12}})
if (liked.liked.length<12){
   let existingLiked = []
   for (const e of liked.liked) existingLiked.push(e._id)
   likedArray.liked.splice(((page - 1) * 12),12,...existingLiked)
                    await user.findOneAndUpdate({username: username},{liked:likedArray.liked},{useFindAndModify: false})}
let obj = {liked: liked.liked, count: count}
res.json(obj)
```